# Legend appears, but it does not show color

Tags: r, vegan

I am using R for plotting. When my graph plots the legend appears where I want it to be but the colors are missing.  `mtcars 2` is a modified version of `mtcars` (one of the pre-loaded data sets) that adds a model and country of origin to the data set. `mtcars.pca` is what I named my redundance analysis (rda function under vegan), and `mtcars.clust` is titled for hierarchical clustering of the continuous factors of mtcars (hclust function of vegan) Below is the code I am using with `mtcars2`.

[image: Example output]

```
pca.fig = ordiplot(mtcars.pca, type = "none", las=1, xlim=c(-15,15), ylim = c(-20,10))        

points(pca.fig, "sites", pch = 19, col = "green", select = mtcars2$origin =="domestic")  
points(pca.fig, "sites", pch = 19, col = "blue", select = mtcars2$origin =="foreign")  

ordiellipse(mtcars.pca, mtcars2$origin, conf = 0.95, label = FALSE) 
ordicluster(mtcars.pca, mtcars.clust, col = "gray")   

legend("bottomright", title="Car Origin", c("domestic", "foreign"), col = "origin")
```

Comment: please provide a reproducible example, what is mtcars.pca? what is mtcars2? What is mtcars.clust?

Comment: My apologize, mtcars 2 is a modified version of mtcars (one of the pre-loaded data sets).  that adds a model and country of origin to the data set.  Mtcars.pca is what I named my redundance analysis (rda function under vegan), and mtcars.clust is titled for hierarchical clustering of the continuous factors of mtcars (hclust function of vegan)

Comment: use either `col=c("blue", "green"), lty = 1` or `fill=c("blue", "green")` [change to suit your needs]

Comment: user20650  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify a vector of colours in `legend` and also a `pch`:

```
library("vegan")
data(dune, dune.env)
ord <- rda(dune)
plot(ord, type = "n")
cols <- c("red","blue","green")
points(ord, col = cols[dune.env$Use], pch = 19)
legend("bottomright", legend = levels(dune.env$Use), bty = "n",
       col = cols, pch = 19)
```

If you don't add `pch` but just use `col = cols` `legend()` doesn't display any points. Because you used `pch = 19` in your `points()` calls, use the same in the `legend()` call.

Also, note how to plot points of different colours in a single pass. I have some examples and explanation that go through the *indexing* trick I used in my code above to achieve this in a blog post of mine from a few years ago: http://www.fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2012/04/11/customising-vegans-ordination-plots/

Answer (score 0):

I came to this question having the next problem in xts object:
I wanted to plot all time-series in xts object with legend. Moreover, there were around 20.

- I used (wrong):

```
plot(returns_xts)
addLegend(...)
```

- Correct version:

```
plot(returns_xts, legend.loc = "bottomright", col=1:20, lty = 1)
```

- There is **legend.loc** parameter
- col = **1:20** generates colors for you

Result:
[image]